# Query will work in the designer but not in code

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have used this type of structure several times with no problem but this time I get a "type incompatibility" error message (error 13).
The SQL statement returns results when I run it throught he query designer.

```
Dim cSQL As String
Dim rsAlertes As Recordset

cSQL = "SELECT Detail.[DATE RECEPTION], Detail.FOURNISSEUR, Detail.[N° DE COMMANDE], Non_comformite.Nature_default " & _
            "FROM Detail INNER JOIN Non_comformite ON Detail.[N° DE COMMANDE] = Non_comformite.PO " & _
            "WHERE Detail.Alerte = True " & _
            "ORDER BY Detail.[N° DE COMMANDE]"

Set rsAlertes = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(cSQL) *** This is where I get the error 

If rsAlertes.RecordCount = 0 Then
    DoCmd.Close
End If
```

Thank you for any help or suggestion.